# Trying to subtract from a list of lists at a constant rate

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to have a bunch of lists of related values, and I want the numbers to all decrease at the same rate. For example:

```
myList=["dog", 5]
myList1=["cat", 3]

biglist=[myList, myList1]

#have all numeral values in biglist decrease by 1
biglist-=1
print(biglist)
```

This script obviously doesn't work because you can't subtract one from a list, and I am not quite sure what to ask to find out what to do here, so I'd appreciate some help getting un-stuck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a list comprehension:

```
myList = ["dog", 5]
myList1 = ["cat", 3]

biglist = [myList, myList1]

res = [[i, j-1] for i, j in biglist]
```

---

If you do not wish to create a new list, you can use a regular `for` loop, iterating over a `range`:

```
for i in range(len(biglist)):
    biglist[i][1] -= 1

print(biglist)

[['dog', 4], ['cat', 2]]
```

Comment: In second example, you can simply do: `for sl in biglist: sl[1]-=1`